# How to make use of Java's Graph Class?

Tags: java, eclipse, graph, import, utilities

So this is definitely a simple problem most likely with a simple fix but I just cannot figure out the issue here.

I am trying to make use of Java's Graph class:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/javax/ide/util/Graph.html

however, I am unable to import javax.ide. There are many other packages/methods beginning with javax. that I am able to import as displayed in eclipse but javax.ide is not one of them:

[image: javax imports]

I am, however, able to import java.util.AbstractCollection but my program still cannot resolve Graph to a type when I do this.

My guess is that the class is simply not in the library, I have tried updating my JDK but it doesn't seem to have changed anything. I apologize for my ignorance here, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well have you installed the "IDE API (JSR-198)" which the documentation you've linked to is about? The `Graph` class is not part of the standard JRE...

Comment: I would say that is probably it, although I cannot find any download links for the IDE

Answer (score 0):

javax.ide.util is not part of the standard JDK. The link in the question takes you to an Oracle Fusion Middleware API subsection, which includes [IDE API (JSR-198)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=198). You need to install additional libraries (probably Oracle Fusion Middleware) to get this package, but that would be an overkill to just get a graph library. It's better to evaluate your requirement and see what graph library suits your needs.